# How to call httppost action from ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.ActionLink("PostActionName","MyController")
```

Here I want to call `PostActionName` which having `HttpPost` Verb.
Currentlly i am not able to call `PostActionName`. It only calling HttpGet verb Action.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the case ( if is not please provide some code for preview) bu i guess you have to put 
`[HttpPost]`
`public ActionResult NameOfAction`
 attribute above :)

Comment: A link makes a GET, not a post. You need to submit a form to a `[HttpPost]` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call POST Action method using `@Html.ActionLink,` instead you can use `@Ajax.ActionLink` to call a POST action method. 
Firstly you need Scripts

```
<script src="∼/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="∼/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

 @Ajax.ActionLink("Action Name", "PostActionName", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post"})
```